# Android 12 splash screen , Navigate to various activity after splash screen as per the condition

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, android-12

In my app i'm trying to implement android 12 splash screen in which after used authentication they will be navigated to the Home activity instead of login activity after splash screen but it's not working. I have already specified in android manifest as well as dependencies as specified in official document.  I'm confused where to apply these conditions.
Example will be good

My splash theme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="theme.app.start" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/logo</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My previous splash activity

```
if (UserInformation.getID(this).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                activityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            } else {
                activityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            }
            finish();
            startActivity(activityIntent);

        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate#prevent_the_custom_activity_from_displaying

Comment: i used splashScreenSetonScreenCondition but it is not working app get crash as soon as i run it

Answer (score 0):

Splash activity

```
Intent activityIntent;
        if (UserInformation.getID(this).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            activityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        } else {
            activityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        }
        
        startActivity(activityIntent);
        finish();
```

> UserInformation.getID() return value empty, so thats why intent to LoginActivity.class

Comment: it was working before as i created a separate activity for splash screen but now i want to integrate it into  Login activity/Home activity as recorded in the document but it is not working, my doubt is where and how to add these condition in the code so that just after splash screen i can navigate to either of these two according to condition

Comment: More code require to clarify your problem. If you feel free than share at least code of your LoginActivity or UserInformation or UserInformation.getID function to understand your exact problem. 

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Handle the splash screen transition.
      SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

      // Keep the splash screen visible for this Activity
      splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition(() -> false );

      if (!UserInformation.getID(this).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
      }
```